# Why is Observable.Finally not called when Observable.Generate finishes?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I needed to alternate between two states with each state having a different interval time.
The best way I could think of doing this was to use Reactive Extensions' Observable.Generate
which is pretty awsome.

From what I read on msdn and other sites, Observable.Finally() should fire if the
observable "terminates gracefully or exceptionally".  I was testing the following code
(in LINQPad) to see how it works, but I can not get .Finall() to fire at all.

```
var ia = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
var ib = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.2);
var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
var ct = new CancellationTokenSource();

var o = Observable.Generate(
    true,
//    s => !ct.IsCancellationRequested,
    s => (DateTime.UtcNow-start) < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3) && !ct.IsCancellationRequested,
    s => !s,
    s => s ? "on" : "off",
    s => s? ib : ia)
//    .TakeUntil(start+TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
    .Concat(Observable.Return("end"));


o.Subscribe( s=> s.Dump(), ct.Token);
var t = o.ToTask(ct.Token);


t.ContinueWith(x => x.Dump("done"));
o.Finally(() => "finallY".Dump()); // never gets called?

Thread.Sleep(10000);
ct.Cancel();
```

If I make Thread.Sleep 10s, the observable sequence finishes and the Task.ContinueWith fires, 
but not .Finally().

If I make Thread.Sleep 2s, the observable sequence is canceled and the Task.ContinueWith again fires,
but not .Finally().

Why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the return type of the `Finally` method; should give you a hint.  Just like the `Concat` method returns a *new* `IObservable` with the new sequence concatenated to it, but doesn't change the original, the `Finally` method returns a new `IObservable` that has that final action, but you're subscribing to the original `IObservable`. Put the following line in front of your `Subscribe` call and it'll work.

```
o = o.Finally(() => "finallY".Dump());
```

I agree it's an odd API choice though; I'd think of `Finally` as being more akin to `Subscribe` than to `Concat`.  You're *subscribing* to the finally "event"; it's odd that the API *forces* you to create a completely new *IObservable* and then subscribe to that just to get the `Finally` thing to happen.  Plus it allows a potential error (made evident if we use the function in your question) that if you subscribe twice to that new *IObservable*, your `Finally` function will execute twice.  So you have to make sure that one of your subscriptions is on the "finallied" *IObservable* and the others are all on the original.  Just seems unusual.

I guess the way to think about it is that `Finally` isn't meant to modify the observable, but rather to modify the subscription itself.  i.e., they don't expect you typically to make openly-accessible named observables that have `Finally` things (`var o = Observable.[...].Finally(...);`) rather it's meant to go inline with the subscription call itself (`var subscription = o.Finally(...).Subscribe(...);`)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. One way to avoid the multiple calls of Finally, though, is to not replace to original IObservable, but only use the new one for a single Subscribe.  Just changing the one line to : `o.Finally(() => "finallY".Dump()).Subscribe();`